# How do the "has" and "whereHas" methods work in Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I have a relationship defined between users and permisson, a user can have many permissions.

When I use "with" I get the data normally.

```
     $user->with('permisson')->get();
```

I get the user with their permissions.

When I use "has" it only returns the user.

```
    $user->has('permission')->get();
```

For what I've read, I should get  the permissons if the user contains at least one permission.

I am using Postgres driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`with` is used for eager loading a relationship. You'd use it to fetch all of the specified relationships for each model (individually, or in a collection).

`has` is for using the relationship as a constraint or filter. As you said, using something like `has('permission')` will add a constraint to the query that says "only get Users that have at least one permission". This *does not* automatically load the relations like `with()`, it only creates the constraint.

You can combine the two if you want to take advantage of both the constraint and eager loading the results.

```php
User::has('permission')->with('permission')->get();
```

Seems a bit redundant, I know.

Answer (score 0):

From laravel docs:

If you wish to limit your results based on the existence of a relationship, you should use the `has` method. For example, if you want to retrieve all blog posts taht have at least one comment, yo may pass the name of the relationship to the `has` and `orHas` methods:

```php
$posts = Post::has('comments')->get();
```

So, when you use the `has` method, it will not return the relationship, but just the post models which has at least one comment.

The `whereHas` and `orWhereHas` methods allows you to add customized constraints to a relationship constraint, such as checking the content of a comment (using the laravel example):

```php
$posts = App\Post::whereHas('comments', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
})->get();
```

When you use the `with` method, you are loading the realtionship with the model:

```php
$user->with('permission')->get()
```

This code will load the user and the permission relationship, while this one

```php
$user->has('permission')->get();
```

will load the user who has some permission.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I used the syntax from the docs and it didn't work, the relationship didn't come.

Comment: and `User::with('permission')->get()`?